# Reset temporary commits, modify, and redo the previous commits again

Tags: git

When I work on a feature branch, I have to commit my temporary works from time to time, so that others can follow my newest changes, but I prefer to show the changes on this branch in my IDE.

The first step I can think of is:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~n
```

But how can I redo those commits so that I can create a new commit based on the original HEAD?

[image]

## Clarify

This is a question about collaboration with others on the same git branch. "b" and "a" (see the image above) are my commits for a big new feature. I commit and push so that others can start their work based on my code. I want to soft reset because I want to see the changed lines in the IDE editor, since this is a big new feature and very complex. When I'm done with my new work, I want to replay commits "b" and "a" because they were soft-reseted and pushed to remote. Then I want to create a new commit "n" and continue works on this new feature.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you please try to clarify?

Comment: Commit as you would normally?

Comment: Unless your IDE messes with things, `git reset --soft` followed by `git commit` already does what I think you want. (I had some trouble understanding what you were asking.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to redo the commits that you have reset?

In that case, go like this

```
git reflog
```

and look for the message of the last commit before you did your reset.

Then reset to that hash.

```
git reset 147ad0
```

or something like that

Then if you chose the right commit, you will now only have the changes you made *since* your big reset as local changes.  If you chose the wrong hash from your reflog, you can try a different one.  You because reset doesn't change the state of your files, you can try resetting over and over again until you like what you see.

Comment: +1 as this is the correct answer. Yet a correct-er answer is "your workflow is broken, google what an AB problem is".